# Open the URL in the same opened tab

Tags: python

I am trying to open the URL from `python` code using web-browser module but I am not able to open the URL in the same opened tab each time.

I am using this function:

```
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath(filename),new=0)
```

Even though i have used `(new = 0)` it is not working , so can anybody find a solution and let me know ?

Thank you advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use `selenium`?

Comment: @Nikhil Param  I did not get your point can you please write down the code here.

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

Comment: @Nikhil Please clear more - how we can open a link in same tab using Python webbrowser or how - if any other thing. Thanks!!